# Clang matcher that hasGlobalStorage but is non-static

Tags: parsing, clang, clang-ast-matchers

I was trying to compose a matcher that finds global variables that does not have static storage

This is what I have so far

```
varDecl(hasGlobalStorage(), isDefinition())
```

Accoring to Clang [AST Matcher Reference](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html)

hasGlobalStorage will also match static variables inside function bodies

[image]

I don't want to match 'y' variable

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use isLocalVarDecl method.

Comment: Yup, thats how I solved it. It may be obvious but it's worth mentioning this needs to be used with negation